# Is oxymetazoline an efficient runny nose treatment?

Tags: medical-science, virus

A proverb says:

"The treated cold lasts seven days and the untreated cold lasts a week".

A pharmaceutical company however [claims in a PR article](http://www.rodina.cz/clanek6002.htm) that its product containing [Oxymetazoline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxymetazoline) will reduce average duration of a runny nose to four days, and that oxymetazoline has a proven antiviral effects:

> shortened runny nose treatment ... about one third ... patients were treated only for four days, instead of six days for those using Saline.
>
> proved beyond any doubt antiviral effect of oxymetazoline

The PR article mentions a study by Dr. Stephan Kölsch from Merck Selbstmedikation GmbH,  Darmstadt from September 2005, with no further references.

Are those claims true (none of this is mentioned on [runny nose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhinorrhea) or [oxymetazoline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxymetazoline) Wikipedia pages)?

Comment: Well, at least [the study doesn’t appear in PubMed](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed?term=K%C3%B6lsch%20S%5BAuthor%5D) and the [official Nasivin homepage](http://www.nasivin.de/) doesn’t mention the study, and nor does the package insert.